If older than todays date > change "published" to "draft" (Wordpress)
I'm using a plugin that allowes users to post events frontend.
They can choose publishing date, and expire date.
The plugin does its job by "unpublishing" events at the correct date, but is not "unpublished" in wordpress, just hidden in the plugin content output.

So the content will still be found in searches.

I would like to set up a cron job that runs a script once every day, that checks the database like this:
"If event_expire_date = > todays date" then change "published" to "draft or private").
Meta key for expire date:
event_expire_date
I found this script that taps into the idea:
UPDATE yourtable 
SET titleColumn = CONCAT('EXPIRED ', titleColumn) 
WHERE category = 'archived'

Still in the progress of finding the right code for this

You can achieve this by writing a custom query
global $wpdb;

// Define the table names with the appropriate prefixes
$post_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
$meta_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';

// Set up the query to update the post status
$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "UPDATE $post_table
    INNER JOIN $meta_table ON $post_table.ID = $meta_table.post_id
    SET $post_table.post_status = 'draft'
    WHERE $post_table.post_type = 'event'
    AND $meta_table.meta_key = 'event_expire_date'
    AND CAST($meta_table.meta_value AS DATE) >= %s",
    date('Y-m-d')
);

// Execute the query
$wpdb->query($query);

Or You can Write the WP Query and fetch all the expired posts and then loop through them
// Set up the arguments for the query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_expire_date',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);

// Get the posts
$event_query = new WP_Query($args);

// Loop through the posts and update their status
if ($event_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($event_query->have_posts()) {
        $event_query->the_post();
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => get_the_ID(),
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        ));
    }
}

// Reset post data
wp_reset_postdata();

Here I am assuming that you custom post type is event, change it if you are using different slug for that.
